# Fill in column based on values in other columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to determine the value of a column based on the value of 3 other columns.

The logic is, if `ColC` contains the string value 'Deck', populate the new column (`ColD`) with the value 'Deck'. If not, check `ColB` for the word 'Deck'. If it's not there, check `ColA`. If not there, just set `ColD` to empty.

However, I then want to repeat the same process, but for the word 'Beam'. Then again for the word 'Wall', then one last time with the word 'Grating'.

Here's a snippet of the data:

```
ColA    ColB                  ColC
Deck    DECK PENETRATION        
        DECK        
Deck            
        WALL PENETRATION        
        PRIMARY GRATING                 
Beam                          PRIMARY BEAM PENE
```

This is what the above should end up looking like:

```
ColA    ColB                 ColC                       ColD
Deck    DECK PENETRATION                                Deck
        DECK                                            Deck
Deck                                                    Deck
        WALL PENETRATION                                Wall
        PRIMARY GRATING                                 Grating
Beam                         PRIMARY BEAM PENE          Beam
```

There may be other words I'd like to check against ColA-ColC, so ideally the solution would involve passing a list of words to a function of some sort. The list right now would look like `['Deck', 'Beam', 'Wall', 'Grating']`

Although unlikely, if the code finds that one column (e.g. `ColA`) value has the word 'Grating' and another column (e.g. `ColB`) has the word 'Deck' - it would just fill `ColD` with the word 'Conflict'.

I think I can do this using `np.where` but I'm struggling to set something up that works. For example, if the code is checking for the word 'Grating' and doesn't find it, I don't want it to overwrite `ColD` with nothing, where it may have already been populated with the word `Beam`, `Deck`, etc.

Edit:

So something like this *almost* works if I use in conjunction with `df.apply` setting `axis = 1`.

However, in the new column, it only contains values 'Deck' and 'Unset' after running it. Something is off with my logic and understanding of how `apply` works.

```
def my_function(row):
    li = ['Deck', 'Grating', 'Wall', 'Beam']
    for x in li:
        if x.lower() in row.A.lower():
            return x
        elif x.lower() in row.B.lower():
            return x
        elif x.lower() in row.C.lower():
            return x
        else:
            return 'unset' 


df['ColD'] = df.apply(my_function, axis = 1)
```

Comment: have you considered using the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function with axis=1? You just define a function that accepts a single parameter (row), and the function returns a single value. You can implement the logic you're talking about in the passed in function

Comment: I hadn't actually considered that, thanks. I will give that a shot now.

Comment: @ajoseps I added an edit to my question with the apply method. Not quite sure how to get it working for my case. It's not giving me the right output as of yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach. I changed your input so that the first row would lead to a conflict

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(
"""
ColA,ColB,ColC
Deck,DECK PENETRATION, BEAM
,DECK,
Deck,,
,WALL PENETRATION,
,PRIMARY GRATING,
Beam,,PRIMARY BEAM PENE
"""))

df['ColD'] = None

words = ['Deck', 'Beam', 'Wall', 'Grating']

#join the rows together as strings to search through
row_text = df.fillna('').sum(axis=1).str.lower()

for word in words:
    contains_inds = row_text.str.contains(word.lower())
    
    inds_to_fill = contains_inds & df['ColD'].isnull()
    inds_to_conflict = contains_inds & df['ColD'].notnull()
    
    df.loc[inds_to_fill,'ColD'] = word
    df.loc[inds_to_conflict,'ColD'] = 'Conflict'
    
df
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. I should have noted that my data frame contains more than just 3 columns. I only included 3 for the example. Your example looks like it may be checking the whole row? Also I did edit my question with a new way I was trying to do it, but wasn't having luck with.

Comment: you're right it is currently checking the whole row. quick change to only look through A,B,C is `row_text = df[['ColA','ColB','ColC']].fillna('').sum(axis=1).str.lower()`

Comment: Nice. As far as I can tell, that's worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: great! there is an edge case I just realized that could be a problem with this approach. If the end of ColA is "BE" and the start of ColB is "AM" then "BEAM" will show up in the concatenated line even though it isn't in A or B

Comment: That's fine. I don't think that would ever happen. One last thing, I'm trying to add a final line, where if there's a conflict, give precedence to `ColB`. As in, if `ColB` has the word Grating, and `ColC` has the word Deck - rather than writing conflict, just use the word Grating. Unable to get this working.